# Как пользоваться Ultisnips в vim

Tags: vim

Установил плагин Ultisnips на vim, вроде все по инструкции, но, зараза, не работает. Руководства на русском не нашел. Мой .vimrc:

```
" UltiSnips
let g:UltiSnipsUsePythonVersion = 3
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=$HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips'
```

Другие плагины работают. Использую vundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема! Вместо

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=$HOME.'/.vim/UltiSnips'
```

Нужно записать

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnips"]
```